Windows Form process has exited with unexpected exit code
From a Windows application developed in .Net framework 4.8, clicking on a button is trying to launch another Windows application that is in a different project (to maintain legacy behavior).
After running the legacy application I am showing the process id in a log textbox and then closing the current application.
var appProcess = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "LegacyApp.exe",
    UseShellExecute = false
};
var legacyProcess = Process.Start(appProcess);
ShowOutput($"Process: {legacyProcess.Id}");

Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

The process starts correctly, I can see the process id both in my output and in the list of processes in the Windows task manager. But after a few seconds, approximately 2-3, the process goes into the "Suspended" state and then closes.
Any idea why this is happening?
Am I using the correct way to launch the new application and close the current one?

Can you successfully run the other program from Explorer or the command-line?

It seems very odd that you're calling Kill on the current process. Not sure that that would be related to your issue, but why are you not using Application.Exit or the like to exit the current app?

Impossible to guess without seeing the code for LegacyApp.

Does LegacyApp.exe has dependencies of its own? And as you are not setting a specific WorkingDirectory for the process it might have problems finding those. If not played with the WorkingDirectory in the starting app you are using the directory the starting app is in not the one LegacyApp.exe might be in.

@Ralf both executables are in the same directory, along with their dependencies.

@500-InternalServerError no, from explorer or cmd get same error

@jmcilhinney i can try with Application.Exit but without killing the current process also get the same issue

@JohanPino: Then the issue is unrelated to the code that you show here.
